# ksqldb using subject name strategy TopicRecordNameStrategy

Tags: ksqldb

I have seen and try many examples of ksql stream using avro but it seems that it does not have support for TopicRecordNameStrategy. Is
it possible create a stream for a topic using subject strategy name TopicRecordNameStrategy?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is 'no', or at least I don't think so.

ksqlDB requires the data in each Kafka record to follow a common schema. This is because SQL is itself strongly typed.  When you create a stream or table over an existing topic, ksqlDB uses this common schema to define the set of columns in the stream or table.

```sql
-- value columns of the CLICKS stream are loaded from the Schema Registry
-- from under the subject 'clicks-value'.
CREATE STREAM CLICKS
  WITH (
    VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', 
    KAFKA_TOPIC='users'
  );
```

With `TopicRecordNameStrategy`, each record can have a totally different schema, i.e. a totally different set of columns.  So what columns should ksqlDB use to define the columns in the table or stream?  Handling this is more tricky.

It may be possible to explicitly provide the table's columns when declaring the source, but this too may fail - I'm not sure without trying it:

```sql
-- explicitly define the columns:
CREATE STREAM CLICKS
  (
    URL STRING,
    USER_ID INT
  )
  WITH (
    VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', 
    KAFKA_TOPIC='clicks'
  );
```

If this doesn't work, then consider raising an [enhancement request in Github](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement%2C+needs-triage&template=feature---enhancement-request.md&title=), as it should be possible to support the strategy by simply capturing all the schemas currently registered and creating a schema that is the union of all columns.